# How to get microsoft.xrm.client.codegeneration.dll

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to set up references to the CRM 2011 sdk

```
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll
Microsoft.Xrm.Portal.dll
Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll
```

While trying to use the CrmSvcUtil.exe to generate the early bound types for CRM, I get an error  Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.dll cannot be located. I could not locate the dll in any of the packages that I downloaded using Nuget PM.

Can anybody advise on the usage and how to obtain this?

Comment: You should download the XRM 2011 SDK to use the CrmSvcUtil.exe. In case if you have multiple versions of the XRM SDK, make sure you are running the correct version of CrmSvcUtil

Comment: That is done. I navigate to folder which contains the CrmSvcUtil.exe and run the command there, it now gives me the error - The system cannot find the file specified. I am not sure what file it is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Early Bound Generator in the [XrmToolBox Tool Store](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/). It contains the functionality to generate code using the Xrm.Client.  Or if you really just want to use the DLL and do everything by hand, it contains the DLL in the download.

### Update

As of March 2020, the EBG no longer supports the deprecated Microsoft.Xrm.Client usage.  Hopefully you've transitioned off of that.  You can still download older versions of the EBG on NuGet if you're stuck on that client generation.